# error with pr2_apps

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to install pr2_apps, but I get this error. Can someone please explain how to solve this problem?

summit@V3:~$ sudo apt-get install ros-electric-pr2-apps
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Couldn't find package ros-electric-pr2-apps

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/61130/error-with-pr2_apps/) by [agrirobot-George](https://answers.ros.org/users/3227/agrirobot-george/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-04-18

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) on 2013-04-19**:
I just checked, and in Ubuntu 11.10 (amd64), the package is there. Which version of Ubuntu are you using?

**Comment by [agrirobot-George](https://answers.ros.org/users/3227/agrirobot-george/) on 2013-04-21**:
Hi, I am using ubuntu oneiric (11.10)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The package is definitely there. Make sure that you have a file called `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros-latest.list` with the following line in it:

```
deb http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu oneiric main
```

Then do a `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install ros-electric-pr2-apps`, and you should be all set. Also see the [Installation instructions](http://www.ros.org/wiki/electric/Installation/Ubuntu).

**Update:** George sent me an email with some screenshots. Your network connection isn't working properly, as you can see from the errors (`unable to resolve host address packages.ros.org` etc.). Once you've fixed that, it should work.

---

Originally posted by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) with karma: 11816 on 2013-04-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [agrirobot-George](https://answers.ros.org/users/3227/agrirobot-george/) on 2013-04-24**:
OK thanks I will try that and let you know what happens

**Comment by [agrirobot-George](https://answers.ros.org/users/3227/agrirobot-george/) on 2013-04-24**:
Dear Martin, I am not sure i understood what i should sent you. Which network connection command  should i run and sent you the output?

**Comment by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) on 2013-04-25**:
Dear George, this is a general Ubuntu networking question, not a ROS question. Try googling "unable to resolve host address", or ask on the general Ubuntu help forums, you'll probably get a better answer there.

**Comment by [agrirobot-George](https://answers.ros.org/users/3227/agrirobot-george/) on 2013-04-25**:
OK! I will. Thanks!